# Why the laws re the burial of slaves in the Twelve Tables?

Tags: ancient-rome, law, slavery

In the Roman Twelve Tables, Table X states:-

> Law X.
>
> The body of no dead slave shall be anointed; nor shall any drinking take place at his funeral, nor a banquet of any kind be instituted in his honor.

Was there any particular reason for this, and why was it considered important enough to be included in the Twelve Tables?

Answer (score 6):

I find at least two different sites that show different translations:

[from here:](http://thelatinlibrary.com/law/12tables.html)

> Anointing by slaves is abolished and every kind of drinking-bout. Let
>   there be no costly sprinkling, . . . no long garlands, . . . no
>   incense-boxes.

[and here:](http://avalon.law.yale.edu/ancient/twelve_tables.asp)

> 6a. ... Anointing by slaves is abolished and every kind of drinking
>   bout ... there shall be no costly sprinkling, no long garlands, no
>   incense boxes ...

These sources both list it as *by slaves*, not *of slaves*. I don't know which is the correct interpretation. You might list your source for reference.

Comment: Seems surprisingly hard to find the original Latin.

Comment: https://archive.org/stream/remainsofoldlati03warmuoft/#page/500/mode/2up (6a near the top) has *"Anointing by slaves is abolished"* as a translation of *"Servilis unctura tollitur"* though I would have thought *"Anointment of a slave is abolished"* might be a more literal translation

Comment: @Henry Good find. That entire section of rules seems to be referencing behavior at funerals, not concerning slaves rights to funerals.  Funny how one world can cause completely different meanings.

Answer (score 3):

Those laws are part of a whole set of [sumptuary laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumptuary_law) that applied not only to slaves, but to citizens as well. For example, another law was that you were not supposed to throw gold into the bier or dress the deceased in more than three robes.

If you read the section on Roman sumptuary laws in the link provided above it summarizes the Roman attitudes towards eschewing luxury.